# Why did Muzan turn into a woman?

Tags: demon-slayer

I know that Muzan is a shapeshifter, and can change his biology and and appearance at will, but why did he specifically choose to turn into a *woman*? What was the reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

if i'm not mistaken, the reason why muzan shape-shift is to hide his real identity or his face from the demon slayers. I think this is also the reason why the pillars were shocked when oyakata-sama revealed that tanjiro had a brief encounter with muzan.

Answer (score 0):

On a serious note, while not directly mentioned in the manga, I imagine the reason Muzan appears as a woman is that it was the form he was using for research purposes. Later in the series we see him take a different form to gain access to research information; the woman persona is likely one that could grant access to different places/ resources/persons. Shifting forms likely wasn't worth the energy or time when addressing the Lower Moons :/

Answer (score 0):

muzan turned into a woman probably to trick the lower moons, he also changed his presence but in that time if a woman had pale skin (like muzan) it was considered beautiful. So I think thats why he became a woman